# Spawn protection when scatering players

Tags: minecraft-commands

I have a mini game that spawns players in random locations when they die. I was wondering if there was a way to make them invincible for 5 seconds.

Comment: Flagging question as unclear because it does not specify which edition is being played.

Answer (score 3):

you can give the players resistance 255 for five seconds using the following command:

```
/effect @a minecraft:resistance 5 255 true
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to type /scoreboard objektives add (name) deathCount in chat.
Then you put a repeat and always active command block facing uppwards with...
testfor @a[score_(objective name) min=1]
And then you put a chain, conditional and always active command block on top of the other one, with...
effect @a[score_(objective name)*min=1] minecraft:resistance 5 255 true
And the at the top of the chain command block you put another chain, conditional and always active command block with...
scoreboard players set @a[score*(objective name)_min=1] (objective name) 1

Thats all I know:-)

Comment: It should be [score_(objective name)_min=1] instead of [score(objective name)min=1]